# Why does it direct me back to login page even user is authenticated?

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

When I log in to the page and refresh the page it takes me back to the login page. What I want to happen is that when user is authenticated still it directs from login page to home page and not the other way around and that it stays on home page even page is refreshed.

This is my app.js:

```
import React from "react"
import { BrowserRouter, Routes, Route, Navigate, useLocation } from "react-router-dom"

import AuthContextProvider from "../Contexts/AuthContext"
import { useAuth } from "../Contexts/AuthContext"

import Login from "../Pages/Authentication/Login"
import Home from "../Pages/Home"

const App = () => {
  return (
    <AuthContextProvider>
      <BrowserRouter>
        <Routes>
          <Route path="/login" element={<Login />} />
          <Route
            path="/home"
            element={
              <RequireAuth>
                <Home />
              </RequireAuth>
            }
          />
        </Routes>
      </BrowserRouter>
    </AuthContextProvider>
  )
}

function RequireAuth({ children }) {
  const { currentUser } = useAuth()
  return currentUser ? children : <Navigate to="/login" replace />
}

export default App
```

this is my auth context:

```
import React, { createContext, useContext, useEffect, useState } from "react"
import { auth } from "../firebase/Firebase-config"
import {
  signInWithEmailAndPassword,
  onAuthStateChanged,
  signOut,
} from "firebase/auth"

const AuthContext = createContext({
  currentUser: null,
  login: () => Promise,
  logout: () => Promise,
})

export const useAuth = () => useContext(AuthContext)

export default function AuthContextProvider({ children }) {
  const [currentUser, setCurrentUser] = useState(null)

  useEffect(() => {
    const unsubscribe = onAuthStateChanged(auth, (user) => {
      setCurrentUser(user ? user : null)
    })
    return () => {
      unsubscribe()
    }
  }, [])

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("The user is", currentUser)
  }, [currentUser])

  function login(email, password) {
    return signInWithEmailAndPassword(auth, email, password)
  }

  function logout() {
    return signOut(auth)
  }

  const value = {
    currentUser,
    login,
    logout,
  }
  return <AuthContext.Provider value={value}>{children}</AuthContext.Provider>
}
```

is what the auth context returns

[image]

Comment: what does useAuth return? you may add this file here too. so you can get some help

Comment: @TheWuif I updated my question. It returns the authenticated user object or null if the user is not authenticated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use an `undefined` state if you want.

```
const [currentUser, setCurrentUser] = useState(undefined)
```

than the possible states of `currentUser` will be `undefined`, `null`, or the `user` and you can check for this.
Default it will be `undefined` so just navigate if it is `null`.

```
function RequireAuth({ children }) {
  const { currentUser } = useAuth()
  if(currentUser) {
    return children;
  }
  if(currentUser === null) {
    return <Navigate to="/login" replace />;
  }
  return null;
}
```

Comment: This actually worked, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You are storing your user in a state, that is why. When you refresh the page, everything will comes to his initial value. You do need to use cookies or localStorage with state to maintain the needed informations.

Comment: Like redux store for example?

Comment: I do not know a lot about Redux. You can do it with vanilla `javaScript`. When you log in the user, you store it in your state as you do, but also in localStorage for example, like so `loacalStorage.setItem('user', JSON.stringify(user))`. And you can access it like so `JSON.parse(loacalStorage.getItem('user'))` to verify if the user is logged in after refresh.

Comment: if you use redux, you have to preserve the redux state

Comment: but the answer from @yousoumar is correct, or you use undefined, i will add the example for undefined soon. am writting on it